# modify component view based on url difference

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7

Basically I wish to have only one view to list blog posts on my angular app. So to have the list of blog posts for all, recent and category wise, I will be using only one component.

```
    http://localhost:4200/blog/category/technology
    http://localhost:4200/blog/recent
    http://localhost:4200/blog/post/1
```

the above two url(first and second) will show different listing but on same component.

And my router looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blog', component: BlogpostListComponent},
  {path: 'blog/post/:id', component: BlogpostDetailComponent},
  {path: 'blog/category/:name', component: BlogpostListComponent},
];
```

So how can I make changes to the `BlogpostListComponent` since as of now both all,recent and category wise is showing the same content since I am not aware how can differentiate based upon urls. if I can figure out how to understand the difference in URL pattern then I can make use of `*ngIf` and show different content on different URL in same Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `Router` in your component, then use it to get current URL:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

currentRoute: string;
category: boolean;

constructor(
  private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.currentRoute = this.router.url;

    if (this.currentRoute.includes('category') {
        this.category = true;
    } else {
        this.category = false;
    }
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="category">
    This is category mode.
</div>

<div *ngIf="!category">
    This is regular mode.
</div>
```